# Receive SMS upon button click

Tags: react-native, sms

I am making an app using React Native in Expo CLI. On that app there is a bunch of products and upon selecting a product there will be a "Book" Button and a time slot button , upon selecting the button i(user) will get an SMS , that is "Your Product is Booked at (time) time slot" . How can I achieve this SMS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install expo-sms npm package for this functionality.

Here: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sms/

Install the dependecy

```
npx expo install expo-sms
```

Example:

```
async function sendSMSMessage() {
// Check if the device supports sending SMS
const isAvailable = await SMS.isAvailableAsync();
if (isAvailable) {
const { result } = await SMS.sendSMSAsync(
  ['+1234567890'], // phone numbers
  'Hello, this is a message from my Expo app!'
);
if (result === 'sent') {
  alert('Message sent!');
 } else {
  alert('Message send failed.');
 }
} else {
alert('SMS service is not available on this device.');
 }
}

import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import * as SMS from 'expo-sms';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Button title="Send SMS" onPress={sendSMSMessage} />
  );
}
```

Comment: This is sending the SMS but i want to receive the sms('Your Product is Booked") just like an user receives an OTP message.